# Handle Socket Timeout Exception with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup, socket-timeout-exception

what I´m doing is this:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();
Elements elements= pageSubforum.select(elements);
```

Sometimes this is working, but often I get a

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I could actually solve it. The problem was not the connection, it was the parsing method.

```
int timeout = 0;
Jsoup.parse(url, timeout);
```

The timeout has to be set to zero, so Jsoup interprets it as an infinite timeout.
Hope I can help someone with this in the future.